# How to unit test a component containing q-select using vitest? I want to check if the dropdown appears

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, quasar, vitest

I have a component like this:

```
<template>
  <q-select
    clearable
    :disable='disable'
    emit-value
    :error='error'
    error-message='Invalid Equipment Number'
    fill-input
    hide-dropdown-icon
    hide-selected
    hint='Minimum 4 characters to trigger autocompletion'
    input-debounce='100'
    :label='label'
    :loading='loading'
    map-options
    :model-value='mValue'
    :options='options'
    outlined
    :readonly='readonly'
    use-input
    @clear='onClear'
    @filter='filterFn'
    @input-value='setValue'
  >

    <template v-slot:no-option>
      <q-item>
        <q-item-section class='text-grey'>No results</q-item-section>
      </q-item>
    </template>
  </q-select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import EquipmentApi from 'modules/Config/models/Equipment/EquipmentApi'
import { IEquipment } from 'modules/Config/models/Equipment/EquipmentInterface'
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyEquipment',
  props: {
    value: {
      required: false,
      type: Number
    },
    label: {
      required: false,
      default: 'Equipment',
      type: String
    },
    readonly: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false
    },
    disable: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false
    },
    error: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: false
    },
  },
  emits: {
    fill(equipment: IEquipment) {
      return equipment
    },
    'update:value'(val: number) {
      return val
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mValue: null as number|null,
      options: [] as number[],
      loading: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isEquipment() {
      return (this.mValue)?.toString().length === 8
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      this.mValue = parseInt(val)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterFn(val: any, update: any, abort:any) {
      if (val.length < 4) {
        abort()
        return
      }
      update(() => {
        this.loading = true
        EquipmentApi.filter(val).then((response: { data: number[] }) => {
          this.options = response.data
          this.loading = false
        })
      })
    },
    setValue(val: string|number) {
      this.mValue = parseInt(val)
      this.$emit('update:value', this.mValue)
    },
    onClear() {
      this.mValue = null
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

When I use the component, I need to type at least 4 characters in the input text, and the component will show a dropdown options according to the 4 characters like so:
[image]

But I can't replicate the behavior using vitest unit test. This is the unit test I wrote:

```
import { installQuasarPlugin } from '@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import EquipmentField from 'src/modules/Application/components/Form/EquipmentField.vue'
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds)
  })
}

installQuasarPlugin()
let wrapper = null

describe('Equipment field unit test', async () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(EquipmentField)
  })

  it('should have a list of equipment code after we fill the input, and the list\'s first row has text in it', async () => {
    wrapper.find('input').setValue('1234')

    sleep(2000)

    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[role=option]').length) // length = 0. It means the dropdown is not created
  })
})
```

I have found out that in real usage, filterFn function gets called and the options get populated. But not in unit test.
So how to trigger the filterFn function in vitest unit test? The goal is to make the dropdown appears. Because I'm sure the dropdown is not appearing in my unit test.

Here's the minimal reproducible example: github.com/meidikawardana/syncfusion-sample. After clone it, please run these commands: yarn, yarn vitest related src/components/Form/EquipmentField.vue

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me that, reading "[Vue Test Utils / Testing Asynchronous Behavior](https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-async-components.html)", you are trying to test an asynchronous behavior:

The issue you are facing is most likely because your test is not waiting for Vue's reactivity system to update the DOM after you set the input value.

Meaning: when you call `wrapper.find('input').setValue('1234')` in your test, this should trigger Vue's reactivity system to update the state of your component and subsequently the DOM. However, this is not an immediate process - Vue updates the DOM asynchronously to batch changes together and improve performance.

In your test, you are checking the state of the DOM immediately after you set the input value. At this point in time, Vue has not had a chance to update the DOM yet, so the changes you expect to see are not there.

That is where a [package `flushPromises`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises) can come in handy:

> Flush all pending resolved promise handlers. Useful in tests.

`flushPromises` waits for all pending promises to resolve, effectively allowing Vue to update the DOM before you perform your assertions.

Try updating your test like this:

```js
import { flushPromises } from '@vue/test-utils'
// other imports...

describe('Equipment field unit test', async () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(EquipmentField)
  })

  it('should have a list of equipment code after we fill the input, and the list\'s first row has text in it', async () => {
    wrapper.find('input').setValue('1234')

    await flushPromises()

    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[role=option]').length)
  })
})
```

This should cause your test to wait for Vue to update the DOM before you check the state of your dropdown.

Ideally, `filterFn` would also have to be mocked for the test to work correctly, because it is not advisable to make actual API calls in unit tests. Use a mocking library to mock `EquipmentApi.filter` method and return some predefined data.
That would help, since `filterFn` method itself is an async function and it might take some time for the dropdown to appear. To deal with this, you can use [`jest.useFakeTimers()` along with `jest.runAllTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks#enable-fake-timers) to advance all timers. This will allow any timeouts or intervals within your code to immediately execute.

For example:

```js
import { flushPromises } from '@vue/test-utils'
// other imports...

jest.useFakeTimers()

describe('Equipment field unit test', async () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(EquipmentField)
  })

  it('should have a list of equipment code after we fill the input, and the list\'s first row has text in it', async () => {
    wrapper.find('input').setValue('1234')

    await flushPromises()
    
    jest.runAllTimers()

    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[role=option]').length)
  })
})
```

Remember to restore the timers after the tests, you can use `afterAll(() => jest.useRealTimers())` to do this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have tried both `flushPromises()` and `useFakeTimers`, both have no effect on the unit test result and the dropdown still not appears

Comment: @Dika That is unfortunate, considering `flushPromises()` should have been effective here. It's possible that the issue is related to a specific behavior or property of the q-select component, or it might be a limitation or a bug in Vitest or the Quasar App Extension for Vitest. To continue investigating this issue, I would recommend creating a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: here's the minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/meidikawardana/syncfusion-sample. After clone it, please run these commands: `yarn`, `yarn vitest related src/components/Form/EquipmentField.vue`

Comment: Thank you for this project: you can edit your question and include it there. I am not sure why it is not working: it might be due to the way Quasar handles async events differently from vanilla Vue, or some other reason related to your specific setup.